# nlohmann json cannot assign std::string

Tags: c++, cmake, c++17, nlohmann-json

I am puzzled that this very basic code does not compile on windows with msvc 16.8.3 and c++17 (compiles fine with gcc)

```
#include "json.hpp"
#include <string>
int main() {
  nlohmann::json j;
  j["mykey"] = std::string("my value");
  return 0;
}
```

It fails immediately with:

```
no operator "=" matches these operands -- operand types are: nlohmann::basic_json<std::map, std::vector, std::string, bool, int64_t, uint64_t, double, std::allocator, nlohmann::adl_serializer, std::vector<uint8_t, std::allocator<uint8_t>>> = std::stringC/C++(349)

json.hpp(18662,17): message : could be 'nlohmann::basic_json<std::map,std::vector,std::string,bool,int64_t,uint64_t,double,std::allocator,nlohmann::adl_serializer,std::vector<uint8_t,std::allocator<uint8_t>>> &nlohmann::basic_json<std::map,std::vector,std::string,bool,int64_t,uint64_t,double,std::allocator,nlohmann::adl_serializer,std::vector<uint8_t,std::allocator<uint8_t>>>::operator =(nlohmann::basic_json<std::map,std::vector,std::string,bool,int64_t,uint64_t,double,std::allocator,nlohmann::adl_serializer,std::vector<uint8_t,std::allocator<uint8_t>>>) noexcept'

message : while trying to match the argument list '(nlohmann::basic_json<std::map,std::vector,std::string,bool,int64_t,uint64_t,double,std::allocator,nlohmann::adl_serializer,std::vector<uint8_t,std::allocator<uint8_t>>>, std::string)'
```

My CMakeLists.txt is super simple:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(api LANGUAGES CXX)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
add_executable(jsontest main.cpp json.hpp)
```

Comment: On my machine your example compiles just fine. MSVC 19.16, nlohmann json 3.8.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you need to use `json.parse()` to create the string object.

```
j["mykey"] = nlohmann::json.parse("my value");
```

But it's been a while since I last used the library.